# Determine if enough change for tickets in line – 1 test case failed

Tags: javascript, for-loop, functional-programming, codewarrior

For this Kata Level 6 problem on CodeWars, *8* out of 9 tests passed. Strange thing: CodeWars wouldn't tell me which test case failed.

Here is my code. Maybe someone on here could help? Thank you so much.

```
function tickets(peopleInLine) {
  var totalChange = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
    if (peopleInLine[i] === 25) totalChange += 25;
    if (peopleInLine[i] > 25) {
      var change = peopleInLine[i] - 25;
      if (totalChange < change) return "NO";
      if (totalChange >= change) totalChange -= change;      
    }
  }
  return "YES";
}
```

And here is **the question**:

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?

Return **YES**, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change. Otherwise return **NO**.

Examples:

```
tickets([25, 25, 50]) // => YES 
tickets([25, 100]) // => NO. Vasya will not have enough money to give change to 100 dollars
```

Comment: I think you need to keep track of the *bills* you have, not just a total.

Answer (score 3):

You need to count each bill you have: If someone give you 100, you cannot give him back 75 with just one 100 bill. `tickets([25,25,25, 100,100])` should return `"NO"`
Here's a naive solution,

```
function tickets(peopleInLine) {
  //var totalChange = 0; not needed
  var total25bill = 0;
  var total50bill = 0;
  var total100bill = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
    //totalChange += peopleInLine[i]
    if (peopleInLine[i] === 25) {
        total25bill += 1;
    } else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) {
        if (total25bill >= 1) {
            total25bill =-1; //gives back 1 25$ bill 
            total50bill += 1;
        } else {
            return "NO";
        }
    } else if (peopleInLine[i] === 100) {
        if ((total50bill >= 1) && (total25bill >= 1)){
            total25bill =-1; //gives back 1 25$ bill 
            total50bill =-1; //gives back 1 50$ bill 
            total100bill += 1;
        } else if (total25bill >= 3){
            total25bill =-3; //gives back 3 25$ bill 
            total100bill += 1;
        } else {
            return "NO";
        }
    }
  }
  return "YES";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Walle points you you will have to keep track of each bill. Below is a recursive definition which has 3 state variables, `a`, `b`, and `c`, one for keeping track of each bill type.

```
function isEmpty(xs) { return xs.length === 0; }
function first(xs) { return xs[0]; }
function rest(xs) { return xs.slice(1); }

function tickets(xs) {
  function loop(a,b,c,xs) {
    // validate drawer, a=$25, b=$50, c=$100
    if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0)
      return "NO";

    // if the drawer is valid and the line of people is empty...
    else if (isEmpty(xs))
      return "YES";

    // otherwise, process the next person in line
    else
      switch (first(xs)) {
        case 25:                                
          return loop(a+1, b,   c, rest(xs)); // give back $0
        case 50:
          return loop(a-1, b+1, c, rest(xs)); // give back $25
        case 100:
          return b > 0                          // if drawer has a $50..
            ? loop(a-1, b-1, c+1, rest(xs))     // give back $25 + $50 
            : loop(a-3, b,   c+1, rest(xs))     // give back 3 * $25
          ;
      }
  }
  // start the loop with 0 of each bill in the drawer
  return loop(0,0,0,xs);
}
```

I like this function because there's no duplication of logic and there's only one sensible return value for each branch in the loop.

I also like that the case analysis looks like a transaction for each bill type.

```
// in the case of someone paying with a $50
// give 1 a
// gain 1 b
// c stays the same
return loop(a-1, b+1, c, rest(xs))
```

These sort of state changes make it very easy to reason about the program's behaviour.

---

Simplest case, 1 person with a $25

```
tickets([25])
=> 'YES'
```

1 person with a $50. There is no change to give him :(

```
tickets([50])
//=> 'NO'
```

1 person with a $100. Also no change for this person

```
tickets([100])
//=> 'NO'
```

2 people, first with a $25. The second person with $50 gets the $25 in change

```
tickets([25,50])
//=> 'YES'
```

3 people. first with $25. The second person gets the first person's $25 in change. We cannot make change for the third person with only $50 in the drawer.

```
tickets([25,50,100])
//=> 'NO'
```

Same scenario as above but there is an extra $25 before we process the $100 bill. This time we have adequate change.

```
tickets([25,50,25,100])
//=> 'YES'
```

It would also work if 3x $25 came before the $100 bill, because 3* $25 ($75) is valid change for the $100.

```
tickets([25,25,25,100])
//=> 'YES'
```